# Two different spacing distances between grid lines in Chart.js

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, chart.js2

Is it possible to do something like this using Chart.js

[image]

I searched for an example on the internet but could not find it. I need to show 3 lines on the graph because I want to. Two lines range from 0 to 100, while the third varies in the range of 20 to 30. The third line is the most important and if the graph looked like this it would be more credible to see its curve. Currently with the same spacing the third line curves look pretty straight.

Comment: Not possible in chart.js v2

Comment: Is it possible with chart.js v3?

Comment: yes, you can use a stacked axis: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/scales/stacked.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know of any similar done example explained on the internet.